# Test large number of webservices on a single computer

Tags: java, web-services, jetty

We have a large system of physical devices which all run a web service for control and a central control system for controlling these devices. I need to make a substitute for such a physical device in order to test the controlling unit. How will I go about running more than one instance of a test device on a single computer. The protocol used in SOAP with a wsdl written in stone. In addition to the webservice each test device needs a webserver to monitor state and generating events.

My first approach is to embed jetty and use axis2 for webservices, but I am having some trouble making that fly. I managed to get the axis2 SimpleHttpServer working with a webservice, but as far as I can tell SimpleHttpServer will not let me run Servlets or let alone wars. Is there a better approach I am missing?

I considered making a proxy server listening on any number of ports and forwarding the request to a webservice to a central webservice with an additional paramater saying which port the request originated from, but since the wsdl is writting in stone I can not pass this paramater along.

EDIT: I am using Netbeans to generate a webservice for me. Works as a charm but not enough for my project. For some reason wsimport chokes on the wsdl. I don't understand how Netbeans can deploy to the bundled Glassfish server, but if I drop the generated dist/my-project.war into tomcat the webservice doesn't work. Much less show up in web.xml. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've figured out a solution. I can use Glassfish. Then I deploy the same webapp multiple times under different names. Then I have a small proxy made in glassfish which listens on a number of ports and then translates the request to one of the instances running i glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

Axis2 is not meant to be used as a servlet container, so using `SimpleHttpServer` doesn't help you there.

But Jetty is a full featured Servlet container. If you want to make it work, you have to run your Wars with Jetty. (Or any other [servlet container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Servlet_containers), but Jetty is perfectly fine)

I'm not Jetty expert, but this should work:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
Context root = new Context(server, "/", Context.SESSIONS);
root.addServlet(new ServletHolder( yourServletInstance ), "/*");
server.start();
```

(Taken from [Jetty Wiki](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty))

Comment: So what are the steps required to run webservices in jetty

Comment: Where is yourServletInstance coming from and what tools should i use to make it?

Comment: It's an instance of the servlets you mentioned in your question. Normally they can just be instantiated like any POJO, `new MyWebServiceServlet()`, unless you designed your servlet to be instantiated in any other way. (Factory or something)

Comment: Yes, that will run servlets, but not webservices

Comment: I thought that was at least one of the problems you have...?

Comment: Well I can run servlets and I can run webservices, but not on the same server which is my main problem.

Comment: OK, sorry, I obviously misunderstood your question.

Comment: Perhaps you can split your original question into different specialized questions and ask them separately. That might get you more answers.

Comment: ok, I might consider that. I am reading up on the different implementations of webservices. I am coming from a .NET background and am wondering why everything has to be so complicated in java. To be fair I don't know how to do it in .NET but I probably won't have to choose between so many different frameworks and implementations of the same interface

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that if you route your network requests through a SOCKS proxy, you can essentially redirect even hardcoded names and ports in the SOCKS proxy to whatever you need.

Comment: The control system does not support SOCKS and it is made by a different vendor so that's a NO GO.

Comment: Schade.  Then consider putting a Transparent Proxy in front of the control system which allows you to proxy any traffic.  http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/TransparentProxy.html#s2

Comment: Thorbjørn, I've implemented a proxy server in Jetty. Then I realized it won't solve my problem since I don't know how to run multiple instances of the same webservice on the same machine.